# Is there online database of vocabulary of proto-languages, like Starling but more accurate?

Tags: reference-request

Starling is notorious for its inaccuracy. Is there something similar but based on more solid sources, like Brill dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

English Wiktionary has a [Reconstruction namespace](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:AllPages&from=&namespace=118).

Although, some proto-languages are covered in more detail than others.

Wiktionary lemmas are also (WP-)categorized by their language, and word type, e.g. [Proto-Japonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Proto-Japonic_lemmas).

Comment: seeing as OP specifically asks for something based on more solid sources I don't think wiktionary works as an answer given the huge number of unsourced reconstructions (even if many of those are, in fact, valid and can be found in reliable sources if you have access to them yourself), at least not without explicitly giving that caveat

Answer (score 1):

The only answer to this at the moment is simply no—unfortunately Wiktionary contains a lot of unsourced entries. However, if you or anyone ambitious wants to such a database could be assembled based on collecting reliable sources for various reconstructions.